# Clarification on \forall in Lean4

Tags: logic, dependent-type, theorem-proving, lean

The following paragraph appears early in the chapter on quantifiers and equality in "Theorem Proving in Lean 4":

> The Calculus of Constructions therefore identifies dependent arrow types with forall-expressions in this way. If p is any expression, ∀ x : α, p is nothing more than alternative notation for (x : α) → p, with the idea that the former is more natural than the latter in cases where p is a proposition. Typically, the expression p will depend on x : α. Recall that, in the case of ordinary function spaces, we could interpret α → β as the special case of (x : α) → β in which β does not depend on x. Similarly, we can think of an implication p → q between propositions as the special case of ∀ x : p, q in which the expression q does not depend on x.

The last sentence mentions the expression `∀ x : p, q`, where `q` can depend on `x`, and compares it to `p → q` where `p` and `q` are propositions.

My question is this: Are there any real examples of `∀ x : p, q` being used when the following hold?

- `p` is a proposition (so `x` is a proof of `p`)
- `q` depends on `x`

In normal mathematics the expression `∀ x : p, q` would be used when `p` is a set rather than a proposition, so this use confuses me.

I tried to come up with examples of `∀ x : p, q` where `p` and `q` are propositions and `q` depends on the proof of `p`. I couldn't find any situations where I've seen this in normal mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

This might not count as a "real [mathematical] example", but [`List.head?_eq_head`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Data/List/Lemmas.html#List.head?_eq_head) seems like an good example

```
@List.head?_eq_head :
  ∀ {α : Type u_1} (l : List α) (h : l ≠ []),
    List.head? l = some (List.head l h)
```

Your `p` is my `l ≠ []` and your `x` is my `h`.

Here [`List.head`](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Data/List/BasicAux.html#List.head) produces the first element of a list; but this operation is impossible if the list is empty, so it has to take a proof that it is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Lean 4 has consolidated ∀ with Π, allegedly to avoid confusing new users (at the cost of confusing older users/mathematicians with previous experience in dependent type theory.) The notation `Π x: p, q` is rare outside discussions of the [Curry-Howard corrspondence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence), but is nevertheless standard in that context; it also appears in [the Wikipedia article for dependent type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type#%CE%A0_type) in general.

The notation does not generally appear elsewhere in math for a simple reason: usually, it doesn't matter which proof of a theorem you use, so never mind having a special notation for meta-level problems about choice of proof, we don't even really have notation for distinguishing proofs in the first place. It is a problem somewhat unique to the field, and so has notation equally unique.